# View not updating despite calling PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have a simple app with a slider and a label. when I move the slider I can see the setter(Points) being called and updating the value, but when calling `PropertyChanged` the label doesn't update.

What I am expecting it to do is to call the `PointsString` getter when PropertyChanged is called. Using the debugger I have confirmed that `ProperyChanged` is being called and that the value of `points` is being updated. Why is the label bound to PointsString not being updated when the points setter is called?

View.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyFirstApp.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MyFirstApp.Views.DetailPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
       <TableView Intent="Form">
           <TableRoot>
               <TableSection Title="Name">
                   <EntryCell Label="Name:" />
                   </TableSection>
                   <TableSection Title="Rating">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <Label Text="Points:"  />
                            <Label Text="{Binding PointsString}">
                                <Label.BindingContext>
                                    <vm:DetailsPageViewModel />
                                </Label.BindingContext>
                            </Label>

                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell> 
                   <ViewCell>
                       <Grid>
                            <Slider Maximum="10" Value="{Binding Points , Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <Slider.BindingContext>
                                    <vm:DetailsPageViewModel/>
                                </Slider.BindingContext>
                            </Slider>
                        </Grid>
                   </ViewCell>
               </TableSection>
           </TableRoot>
       </TableView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

ModelView:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

    class DetailsPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private double points;

        public DetailsPageViewModel()
        {
            points = 4.0;
        }

        public DetailsPageViewModel(double Points) :  this()
        {
            points = Points;
        }

        public double Points
        {
            get { return points; }
            set
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
                points = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PointsString"));
                }

            }
        }

        public string PointsString
        {
            // Lazy load from points value
            get { return points.ToString(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this method  `PropertyChangedEventArgs` defined somewhere? Do you have any error in the debug logs?

Comment: `PropertyChangedEventArgs` is defined in `System.ComponentModel` which is imported at the top -- I will update the code above to include the imports. No errors in the logs, which is why I am struggling with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged - does a better way exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your XAML I suspect that you are creating new view models and not binding to the single view model.

To give some context each time you declare this `<vm:DetailsPageViewModel />` you are in fact creating a new instance of your view model.

You can try using a [Relative binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-an-ancestor).

Essentially you need to change this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding PointsString}">
    <Label.BindingContext>
        <vm:DetailsPageViewModel />
    </Label.BindingContext>
</Label>
```

to something like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:DetailsPageViewModel}}, Path=PointsString}" />
```

To prove my point you could place a breakpoint in the constructor to your `DetailsPageViewModel` and I expect it to hit multiple times.

Comment: or just use a single VM for the entire page

Comment: @Jason that is the result I am hoping they get to. I was assuming the declarations in the OPs post show they are trying to bind back to what they believe is a single VM

Comment: Thanks @Bijington you were quite right I was creating two instances of my view model. I wasn't able to get you code above to work, but tried simply setting the `BindContext` of the Content Page, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Answer by Bijington above -- I was instantiating two instances of the VM. The answer was to set the Binding context of the page and remove the specific BindingContext's

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyFirstApp.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MyFirstApp.Views.DetailPage"
             >
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:DetailsPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
       <TableView Intent="Form">
           <TableRoot>
               <TableSection Title="Name">
                   <EntryCell Label="Name:" />
                   </TableSection>
                   <TableSection Title="Rating">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <Label Text="Points:"  />
                            <Label Text="{Binding PointsString}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell> 
                   <ViewCell>
                       <Grid>
                            <Slider Maximum="10" Value="{Binding Points , Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </Grid>
                   </ViewCell>
               </TableSection>
           </TableRoot>
       </TableView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```